# Google Script reformat getValues result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a small Google script in sheets that grabs a row of data and then I email it. So far its working fine, but I would really like to reformat the body message to look cleaner.

`var bodyData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, 8).getValues();`

bodyData is what i'm sending, which right now is a comma separated line of text:

```
123456,Driver,Destination,BOL,80,Fri Jul 17 2020 15:46:58 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time),Fri Jul 17 2020 15:47:18 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time),Test
```

And this works fine, but I would like to reformat that and clean it up have a string like:

PickUp Number: 123456

Driver: Driver

Destination: Destination

Bill of Lading: BOL

Tons: 80

Date Entered: Fri Jul 17 2020 15:46:58 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

Laste Changed: Fri Jul 17 2020 15:47:19 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

Note: Test

Without the extra blank line I had to put in there to keep it from merging everything together in this post. Any assistance with this matter is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to transform comma separated values (csv) string to a formatted string, you can split the csv string with the string method `split(",")`, which returns an array of values, which you can format however you like.  Example given below.  However, since you can send an HTML email body, consider using the [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) to format the values with an HTML template.

```js
// usage: var desiredString = csvToString(bodyData);

function csvToString(csv) {
  const values = csv.split(",");
  return `Pickup Number: ${values[0]}
Driver: ${values[1]}
Destination: ${values[2]}
Bill of Landing: ${values[3]}
Tons: ${values[3]}
Date Entered: ${values[4]}
Last Changed: ${values[5]}
Note: ${values[6]}`;
}
```

Comment: based off your answer, I was only able to get var formatText = `Pickup Number: ${bodyData[0][0]}` + "%0D%0A" + `Driver: .... to get me the line returns in the email message being created the insert hyperlink formula! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though!